# How to use 'as well as' and 'even'?

Tags: conjunctions

When I was doing my English homework, I came across this question:

> In his research paper Dr Brown suggests that snacking, if done properly, makes people healthier and ***_*_** helps control weight.
>   A. as well as       B. namely       C. even       D. yet

I chose A, but my tutor said the correct answer should be C. But she did not give me a satisfactory explaination. Could you kindly tell me why I can't use *as well as* in this sentence?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> In his research paper Dr Brown suggests that snacking, if done properly, makes people healthier and **as well as** helps control weight.

This is incorrect because *as well as* is a conjunction, so it doesn't make sense after *and* has already been used to join the two clauses. It would be correct to use *as well as* if *and* were not present.

> In his research paper Dr Brown suggests that snacking, if done properly, makes people healthier and **namely** helps control weight.

*Namely* is used to provide a single example to be more specific about what you've already mentioned. It would be correct if you were to write, for example:

> Snacking, if done properly, makes people healthier: **namely, it** helps control weight.

Both *even* and *yet* are grammatically fine in this context, but you're trying to add emphasis (*even*), not introduce a contradiction (*yet*). *Yet* doesn't make sense because *helping control weight* is related to *making people healthier*, not in opposition to it. An example where *yet* would make sense:

> In his research paper Dr Brown suggests that snacking, if done properly, makes people healthier and **yet I still don't believe it.**

Comment: I wouldn't actually use *namely* quite like that - I'd only use it when actually naming something that has referred to before: *The doctor recommended a way to get thinner - namely, the Dr Brown Diet*.

Comment: @psmears: That is the more common (and methinks better) use, but *namely* also has the more generic meaning of *specifically* or *that is*.

Comment: "and as well helps control weight."?

Comment: @starblue: Yes...well, "and as well as", per the question, which is about a fill-in.